# Convert ASCII sign into a string

Tags: c#, string, ascii, n-queens

I want to convert the ASCII Symbol of the crown : http://charmap.de/zeichen/9813 into a string, so I can use it for the GUI from my n-queens programm.

Comment: What's preventing you from doing this?  ASCII is just a way to interpret numbers as actual characters.  But of course, ASCII won't include all the broad characters that the unicode character set does.

Comment: Does it simply use the symbol in the GUI without needing to be written in Unicode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not ASCII, that is an Unicode character. The range of ASCII characters stops at Unicode code point 127 decimal.

To have it in a string literal, use its Unicode code point [MSDN: Old C# Language Specification: 2.4.1 Unicode character escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
string crown = "\u2655"
```

As @jt000 mentioned in their now-removed answer, you do need a font that can render this glyph.

Comment: I fixed the code for you - `\U` always has *8* trailing hex digits, and is usually used for characters outside the BMP.

Comment: You beat me to it... However, the second part of the problem is finding a font that will render it properly.

Comment: If necessary, the black queen is ♛, `"\u265B"`

Comment: Like Eser said in a comment to the question, why not simply use `string crown = "♕";`? This will work fine if the source code file is e.g. UTF-8 (very normal) or UTF-16, UTF-7. If your source code files are in some Windows codepage, consider converting them into UTF-8.